# Does HP Proliant ML110 Gen9 Support SAS DISK

Tags: fdisk

so i did Buy **Proliant ML110 Gen 9** That have Dynamic **Smart Array B140i Raid** with inside
in the first look the Server has 4 Disk port in the front that can connect to SAS Disk so i did buy 2 SAS disk but they doesn't turn-on and i can't find them in the HP smart Storage , i did also connect SATA HDD drive work fine and i can find him using **Linux OS**

when searching in google i did find that the **Smart Array B140i Raid**  doesn't support SAS disk if that true !! mean while HP proliant support SAS Disk and also have SAS Disk Connecter
is there a solution to connect those 2 SAS disk

Comment: Try to group your description into sentences that end with a "." That would make your contribution much easier to read and people will be more likely responding to your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your advise i will try next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `B1*` Smart Array controllers are SATA-only. The disk bay connectors are SAS-compatible only because HP lets you replace it with a "real" P-series controller as an add-on card.

(Also, "Dynamic" means it's not an actual hardware RAID controller, either – it's just fakeraid.)

Comment: So if i want to place those SAS disk i need to buy one of the P-series controller (replace you mean i get take of the B140 that i have)